# How can I inject an animator for ui-view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I apply animation in ui-views?

I found the code

```
// Unfortunately there is no neat way to ask $injector if a service exists
  var $animator; try { $animator = $injector.get('$animator'); } catch (e) { /* do nothing */ }
```

But how can I inject an animator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a relevant question. If you're using a sufficiently recent version of AngularJS (i.e. 1.1.5), it works by itself.

See the documentation for details: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-animate-ui-view-with-ng-animate

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can I give animation like google image search using nesting ui-views.